# Linq query and Foreach on large number of records from SQL database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm working with Entity Framework and Linq. I need to do a query on 2 properties of my object.

I have this object on the database (about 200.000 records):

```
public class DeviceState
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }      
    public int Device_ID { get; set; }
}
```

I need to do a query like this:

```
List<DeviceState> listState = systemDB.DeviceStates.Where(s => s.Device_ID == DeviceID).Where(l => l.TimeStamp > startDate).Where(l => l.TimeStamp < endDate).Where(s => s.StatusCode == "xx").ToList();
foreach (DeviceState status in listState)
{  
   // here I need to save in an object the status code and the time stamp:
   object.StatusCode= status.StatusCode;
   object.TimeStamp = status.TimeStamp; 
}
```

This query takes much time (15 minutes approx). I think that is due to the creation of the list. So I tried this:

```
foreach (DeviceState status in systemDB.DeviceStates.Where(s => s.Device_ID == DeviceID).Where(l => l.TimeStamp > startDate).Where(l => l.TimeStamp < endDate).Where(s => s.StatusCode == "xx"))
{  
   // here I need to save in an object the status code and the time stamp:
   object.StatusCode= status.StatusCode;
   object.TimeStamp = status.TimeStamp; 
}
```

This was much faster in creating the list. But I still have performance problems due to the foreach cycle. It takes 5ms for each element.

I need to find a solution that takes seconds to execute that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do these things to help the generated query.

1. Return only what you need. Now you are returning everything BUT you only ever use TimeStamp so just return that. You are setting StatusCode below however you are already filtering this in the Where clause so you know that all returned items have a `StatusCode` of "xx" so no need to retrieve that too. This is less data coming back across the network and less cycles taken to map that data to objects and less memory that the data takes up.
2. You should look at the generated query by EF. You can do this using a sql profiler tool (Sql Server has one called Sql Profiler). Then look at the query plan and see if there is anything that could benifit you like adding a missing index. This profiling should be done on the database server, not in c#.
3. Consolidate your where clauses because it's easier to read.

Code

```
// list of timestamps from database
var timeStamps = systemDB.DeviceStates.Where(s => s.Device_ID == DeviceID && 
                                                  s.TimeStamp > startDate && 
                                                  s.TimeStamp < endDate &&
                                                  s.StatusCode == "xx")
                                      .Select(x => x.TimeStamp).ToList();
```

If you still wanted your status code because you removed the filter you could do it like this

```
var timeStamps = systemDB.DeviceStates.Where(s => s.Device_ID == DeviceID &&
                                                  s.TimeStamp > startDate && 
                                                  s.TimeStamp < endDate && 
                                                  s.StatusCode == "xx")
                                      .Select(x => new {x.TimeStamp, x.StatusCode})
                                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do thin one where clause

```
List<DeviceState> listState = systemDB.DeviceStates.Where(
                                  l => l.Device_ID == DeviceID 
                               && l.TimeStamp > startDate
                               && l.TimeStamp < endDate 
                               && l.StatusCode == "xx" 
                               ).ToList();
```

then use `for` rather than `foreach`, because `foreach` slower in case of big amount data

```
for (int i = 0; i< listState.Count; i++ )
{  
   object.StatusCode= listState[i].StatusCode;
   object.TimeStamp = listState[i].TimeStamp; 
}
```

Comment: you are filtering by where clause multiple time so its doing same things multiple time definitely it has the performance issue

Comment: also amount of data is a big issue, at some point you have to convert it as list, json or something like that so at that place it take more time for big amount of data

Comment: Yes it seems faster. Can the foreach cause problems with a large amount of data in the list?

Comment: yes foreach have effect on performance in big amount of data also linq, in this case for is more faster that other, I am updating answer with for

Comment: You may also want to consider parallel for to make use of multithreading (provided the in loop operation is thread safe): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784105%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Mostafiz For the record, chained multiple `Where` are equivalent to single `Where` with `&&`, which in EF has absolutely no affect on the performance - both approaches generate one and the same SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Igor's answer already shows the most obvious improvements that you should do in any case.

Now, if you handly lots of data, then you may want to do it in multiple Threads parallel with [System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx). Code (with other improvements):

```
var deviceStateTime = systemDB.DeviceStates.Where(s => s.Device_ID == DeviceID
                        && s.TimeStamp > startDate)
                        && s.TimeStamp < endDate
                        && s.StatusCode == "xx");
Parallel.ForEach(deviceStateTime, (time) =>
                 {
                    object.StatusCode = "xx";
                    object.Timestamp = time;
                 });
```

Please note, that I did not test it (I wrote it down from memory), so I may have mistyped somewhere.